# Recode variable with car - unexpectedly variable (.x value) treated as NA

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dataformat, r-car, recode

My aim is to recode my variable into another variable with an inverted value:

```
f1_1_recAktuell <- recode(Dat_MonatAktuell$f1_1, "1=10; 2=9; 3=8; 4=7; 5=6; 6=5; 7=4; 8=3; 9=2; 10=1")
```

This code has served me know for more than a year, yet out of a sudden I get this error message:

> Warning message: Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default

I guess there's something wrong with the data, yet I cannot find out what. The class of the variable is `integer`, it has no missing values.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (you can use `dput` to share the data).

Comment: You can just do `11-Dat_MonatAktuell$f1_1` if it is just values 1:10 in the vector.  Please check if you are using `dplyr` as there is a `recode` in `dplyr` which can mask the one in `car`.  In that case, do `car::recode(Dat_MonatAktuell$f1_1, "1=10; 2=9; 3=8; 4=7; 5=6; 6=5; 7=4; 8=3; 9=2; 10=1")`

Answer (score 2):

The warning message is due to use of `recode` from `dplyr` (possibly the OP loaded the package?) instead of from `car`.  This happens when `dplyr::recode` masks the same function in `car`.  We can specify the package name before the function as a remedy  i.e. `car::recode`

```
v1 <- 1:10
car::recode(v1, "1=10; 2=9; 3=8; 4=7; 5=6; 6=5; 7=4; 8=3; 9=2; 10=1") 
#[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Also, we can use

```
11-v1 
#[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

---

The warning can be reproduced with `dplyr::recode`

```
 dplyr::recode(v1, "1=10; 2=9; 3=8; 4=7; 5=6; 6=5; 7=4; 8=3; 9=2; 10=1") 
 #[1] "1=10; 2=9; 3=8; 4=7; 5=6; 6=5; 7=4; 8=3; 9=2; 10=1" NA                                                  
 #[3] NA                                                   NA                                                  
 #[5] NA                                                   NA                                                  
 #[7] NA                                                   NA                                                  
 #[9] NA                                                   NA
```

> ```
> Warning message:
>  Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible.
>   Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default
> ```

To get the expected output, we can also use `dplyr::recode` in this way

```
dplyr::recode(v1, `1` = 10, `2` = 9, `3` = 8, `4` = 7, 
                 `5` = 6, `6` = 5, `7`=4, `8` = 3, `9` = 2, `10` = 1)
#[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked out perfectly! recode got masked by dplyr.